# Automapper mapping an object with HAS-A relationship

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

Holla,

I have an data access object as follows:

```
class Foo : IStorable
{
  string name;
  int age;
  .. many more
}
```

I have another object like this:

```
class FooViewModel
{ 
  Foo data;
  Bar moreData;
  Car evenMore
}
```

So i m reading Foo object from database and i have to construct a ViewModel. ViewModel has a Foo object and some other objects as well. I want to map Foo to ViewModel's Foo.

How can i map this with AutoMapper?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>();
```

Would this work? and how would I access get it?

Essentially i have classes with many properties, i want to avoid typing (being lazy)

Comment: I'm not seeing how AutoMapper would help you in this scenario. Can you flesh out your example a little bit more?

Comment: Are you trying to populate `FooViewModel.data` with the property values of another instance of `Foo`?

Comment: @DanM I have updated with more explanation.

Comment: @jamietre yes. that s what i want to do, instead of manually assigning fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FooViewModel should have all of the properties of Foo that you would like to map, not a 'Foo' property.

Then, you will be able to use AutoMapper to map Foo to FooViewModel and any relational dependencies that Foo has will not end up in the FooViewModel.